# Safe navigation operator in Reactjs using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using Reactjs via JSX. Is there any safe navigation operator to use in this method? I tried using question mark operator like "foo?.bar" but I got syntax error.

Comment: @Li357 refer this: [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator)

Comment: If the variable foo is a function parameters you can use the [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) or do the `&&` trick as the answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, there is a babel plugin called @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining that solves this problem.

Answer (score 6):

The safe navigation operator (aka. Elvis operator) is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) in draft status with TC39, so no. Not yet anyway (as of this writing).

But this ugly syntax will get you there without a library. Instead of ...

```
foo?.bar
```

... use this ...

```
(foo||{}).bar||{}
```

It's hard to read but it works and it isn't dependent on a library.

UPDATE: The proposal has reached stage 4, so it will be part of ES2020.

Comment: Can you show an example of multiple nested property access?
ex: `foo.bar.baz.baz2`

Comment: (((foo||{}).bar||{}).baz||{}).baz2||{}  -- Yuck!  Elvis can't come to JavaScript quickly enough!

Comment: A safe navigation operator is **not** the same thing as an [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator). Safe navigation pertains to avoiding property lookups or method calls on `null`, especially when chained.

Answer (score 2):

You can use from `get` method in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) library, like this:

```
import { get } from 'lodash';

get(foo, 'bar1.bar2.bar3.bar4');
```